# How to use third party frameworks in my own framework? (No umbrella framework)

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have my own framework which use some Firebase frameworks. I do **not want** to include these frameworks inside my own, instead the final app should do that work as it has to be. But my question is:

> How can I make use of the functionalities of Firebase database (for example) in my framework?

If I do not import Firebase frameworks into my own framework, I do not have references to them and I do not know how to link them to mine in order to use the API provided by Firebase database.

So what should I do to interact with other frameworks? I would like to have something like:

```
import Firestore // ERROR: No such module 'Firestore'

internal class MyClassInsideMyFramework {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var ref: DocumentReference?

    func addUser(name: String, age: Int) {
        ref = db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["name": name, "age": age])
        // Do more stuff...
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Swift package manager?

Comment: If you don't need a lot of the functionality, then write a protocol, and have the app provide a delegate that implements that protocol. The protocol would be for the functionality you need. You'll then need to have some object in the App implement that protocol, and do the interfacing to Firebase.

Comment: SPM only manage the dependencies and build them into the project, correct me if I am wrong, and it does not solve my problem to connect with other frameworks. And I need the functionalitites implemented by myself because I do not want the final app to write extra code. It could be a good approach but I prefer to keep all automagically for the final app.

Comment: SPM also allows frameworks to define their own dependencies. CocoaPods provides the same kind of functionality. You need to allow a package manage to handle it in any case because the app may import the same framework for other reasons (which is why you're wise to ask the question the way you are).

Comment: I tried SPM and seems it does not support officially iOS yet. And I do not know if I am doing it wrong, but I still can not import the libraries in code. Does someone have another alternative? PS: I am against Cocoapods because I feel it make my project dirty.